# Can't align x-axis on hybrid scatter/area chart

Tags: excel, charts

Please have a look at [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eog8xeszvg3gchw/problem_chart.xlsm?dl=0) Excel chart. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the data:

[image]

There is a scatter series of blue of dots (plus a trendline) and a green area series. The chart data are contained within the series.

The problem I have is that the x-axis values of the two series are not aligned. For example, the second and third blue dots at x = 3.1 and x = 3.8 are in the correct place along the x-axis, but in the green area series they appear to be above x = 2.0 and x = 3.3. How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide example data and screenshot if necessary. most people won't open random excel files from the internet,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Scatter to a Line Chart, then format Line Color so that there is "No Line". Add trendline.

[image]

There may be another way to do this while retaining the Scatterplot, I'm not sure, but this seems to be visually what you're looking for, but I think you will need to use a Line Chart for this unfortunately. The problem is summarized in this similar Q on SuperUser:

https://superuser.com/questions/964264/aligning-stacked-bar-chart-w-scatter-plot-data

> The short answer is that your combining (unsuccessfully) a categorical series (the columns) with interval/ratio series (the line charts). So, Excel doesn't know how to plot your categories (columns) on an interval scale (the current X axis).

You can verify this by selecting Chart > Layout > Axes > Secondary Horizontal Axis > *More Secondary Horizontal Axis Options*. Without making any changes to the axes configuration, the second X-axis will now appear along the bottom of the chart, and you can see it is scaled differently from your Scatter data.

[image]

I.e., in the Scatter series, the data is X/Y pairs. But in your Area chart, it treats the X-values as *categorical*, and in this context "1.1" is no different than "Bob" -- it is a *cardinal* representation of the data rather than an *ordinal* representation.

> The problem I have is that the x-axis values of the two series are not aligned.

So even though the two series appear to share the same set of X-Values, the Chart is simply incapable of treating those as the same *type* of data. The x-axes are not aligned because they are not the same data or even the same type of data!

[image]

All that said, if you change both series to XY Scatter, it is possible (with some extraordinary effort) to apply shading/coloring below a series or between two series, etc.

http://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/

http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/02/13/shaded-line-charts-excel/

Comment: The problem with a line chart is then you lose the correct scaling on the x-axis. You can change the axis type to Date axis, but then e.g. points x = 3.1 and x = 3.7 are piled in top of each other. That's the reason I used a scatter plot in the first place, to get the scaling right.

Comment: @GeorgeSkelton can you please update your post to show actual data values used for both series x- and y- values?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and tips. Think I'll just use another scatter/line for now.

Comment: @GeorgeSkelton that's what I would do. I've seen Peltier's hack before and while it's neat, it seems like an awful lot of effort :)

Comment: Yeah just don't have the time right now. Too bad MSFT doesn't support a date scale < 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is plot the Area graph on a secondary axis. Then go to Chart -> Layout -> Axes -> Display Secondary Horizontal Axis to see the axis, right click for its properties and change the type of the Axis Type to "Date axis". This (kind of) changes the axis to a numerical type, as opposed to a category type.

However, the area graph will still be placed incorrectly too far to the right because Excel will continue to plot the series as a (kind of) category type, with its data points appearing in the centre of each category as opposed to at the correct x value like in an XY scatter plot.

To get the graphs overlaying the most correctly, you can create a Scaled-up x value series which is, say, 1,000 times the original x-values and use this for the x-values of the area plot. By scaling by 1,000 or 10,000, you eventually get the granularity to a point where it looks more like X-Y plot, but is actually an area plot, and the graphs look like they coincide perfectly.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly for me, as I was working with years. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar - I found changing the horizontal axis `Axis position` option to `on tick marks` fixed it.